# Android: How to change the default logging level?

Tags: android, logging

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#isLoggable%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) there are only two ways to change the default logging level from INFO to lower levels (such as DEBUG):

1. `setprop log.tag.<YOUR_LOG_TAG> <LEVEL>`, or
2. `log.tag.<YOUR_LOG_TAG>=<LEVEL>` in /data/local.prop.

**Is it possible to bundle the logging configuration within the application?** I'm looking for the equivalent of `logging.properties` or `logback.xml`, configuration files that are bundled with the application and alter the logging behavior at load-time. The goal is to avoid manually configuring each device that the application will run on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using [logback-android](http://tony19.github.com/logback-android/). I will leave this question open a bit longer in case someone comes up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java logger also here with some customisations..

**ConsoleLogHandler.java**

```
package com.sony.evc.vis.system.util.logger;

import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

import android.util.Log;

public class ConsoleLogHandler extends Handler
{

    @Override
    public void close()
    {}

    @Override
    public void flush()
    {}

    // filter logs and publish them
    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record)
    {
        String className = record.getLoggerName() + ": "
                + simplifyClassName(record.getSourceClassName());
        int threadID = record.getThreadID();
        String methodName = record.getSourceMethodName();
        String msg = record.getMessage();
        int level = record.getLevel().intValue();

        logMessage(className, threadID, methodName, msg, level, record.getThrown());
    }

    // simplify class name from full applied package name to simple class
    private String simplifyClassName(String sourceClassName)
    {
        String fullClassName[] = sourceClassName.split("\\.");
        return fullClassName[fullClassName.length - 1];
    }

    private void logMessage(String className, int threadID, String methodName, String msg,
            int level, Throwable throwable)
    {
        if (level == Level.FINE.intValue()) {
            Log.d(className, "ThreadID:" + threadID + "," + methodName + "()," + msg);
        }
        else if (level == Level.INFO.intValue()) {
            Log.i(className, "ThreadID:" + threadID + "," + methodName + "()," + msg);
        }
        else if (level == Level.WARNING.intValue()) {
            Log.w(className, "ThreadID:" + threadID + "," + methodName + "()," + msg, throwable);
        }
        else if (level == Level.SEVERE.intValue()) {
            Log.e(className, "ThreadID:" + threadID + "," + methodName + "()," + msg, throwable);
        }

    }

}
```

---

create class **LoggerFactory.java**

```
package com.sony.evc.vis.system.util.logger;

import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LoggerFactory {

    public static Logger Log;
    private static ConsoleLogHandler logHandler;
    // Global constants to give programmer choice to add if condition before
    // logging a code.
    public static boolean FINE;
    public static boolean INFO;
    public static boolean WARN;

    // initialise the logger
    public static void init(String version, String globalDebugLevel,
            String appDebugLevel) {

        Log = Logger.getLogger(version);

        // debug level settings
        Level debuglevel = LogLevel.setDebugLevel(globalDebugLevel,
                appDebugLevel);
        if (debuglevel.equals(Level.ALL) || debuglevel.equals(Level.FINE)
                || debuglevel.equals(Level.FINER)
                || debuglevel.equals(Level.FINEST)) {
            FINE = INFO = WARN = true;
        } else if (debuglevel.equals(Level.INFO)) {
            INFO = WARN = true;
        } else if (debuglevel.equals(Level.WARNING)) {
            WARN = true;
        }
        Log.setLevel(debuglevel);

        // logger send its msg to several handlers by default, we have to
        // disable that
        Log.setUseParentHandlers(false);

        // avoid recreation of handler in case activities onCreate() is called
        // again but logHandler is not
        // garbage collected
        if (logHandler == null)
            logHandler = new ConsoleLogHandler();

        // remove previously assigned handlers. This is very important and
        // failing to do so may result in
        // duplication of same logs
        for (Handler handler : Log.getHandlers())
            Log.removeHandler(handler);

        // set this loggers handler and make sure that only one instance is
        // associated with it
        Log.addHandler(logHandler);
    }
}
```

---

create enum **LogLevel.java**

```
package com.sony.evc.vis.system.util.logger;

import java.util.logging.Level;

public enum LogLevel {
    DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, NO_LOG, DISABLE;
    /*
     * set log-debugLevel as per requirement. Global level is given preference
     * over app and service levels. If global level is disabled, other
     * levels are considered
     */
    public static Level setDebugLevel(String sGlobalDebugLevel,
            String sAppDebugLevel) {
        String strGlobalDebugLevel = sGlobalDebugLevel.trim().toUpperCase();
        String strAppDebugLevel = sAppDebugLevel.trim().toUpperCase();
        LogLevel globalDebugLevel = LogLevel.valueOf(strGlobalDebugLevel);
        LogLevel appDebugLevel = LogLevel.valueOf(strAppDebugLevel);
        LogLevel logLevel = globalDebugLevel == LogLevel.DISABLE ? appDebugLevel
                : globalDebugLevel;

        switch (logLevel) {
        case DEBUG:
            return Level.FINE;
        case INFO:
            return Level.INFO;
        case WARNING:
            return Level.WARNING;
        case ERROR:
            return Level.SEVERE;
        case NO_LOG:
            return Level.OFF;
        case DISABLE:
            return Level.OFF;
        default:
            return Level.INFO;
        }
    }
}
```

---

You will also need to update Strings.xml as

```
<!--
    :-Accepted values for global_debuglevel are: "debug", "info", "warning", "error"(in increasing order of priority),No_Log
      and Disable. 
    :-Setting any other value will set "info" level
    -->
    <string name="global_debuglevel">debug</string>

    <!--
    :-Accepted values for app_debuglevel are: "debug", "info", "warning", "error"(in increasing order of priority)
      and No_Log
    :-Setting any other value will set "info" level
    -->
    <string name="app_debuglevel">debug</string>
```

---

From the start of application just init the Logger as

```
    String service_version = getString(R.string.service_version);
    String global_debugLevel = getString(R.string.global_debuglevel);
    String service_debugLevel = getString(R.string.service_debuglevel);
    LoggerFactory.init(service_version, global_debugLevel,
            service_debugLevel);
```

---

For printing Logs write:

```
Log.info(" message ");
Log.fine(" message ");
Log.severe(" message ");
Log.warning(" message ");
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but my question is how to change the application logging level, not how to declare a whole new log handler. Also, your handler fails to handle all possible java.util.logging levels.

Comment: Dear @Gili you shall have been little more polite.